# Serialization in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pickle

I am writing a bot for Discord, the task of the bot is to set a price limit for drains and signal when it reaches it. There are two variables: stock and price. Each sent message in Discord is assigned to these variables. For example, AAPL 127, where aapl is stock and 127 is price. The bot can monitor several lines at once, but when the script is restarted or the Internet connection is lost, all assigned values are reset. The question is whether there is a way to save all these variables in a file and when loading the script, it read them from the file, and it was possible to add and remove the value in this file. I know that there is a pickle for such cases, but not as I could not implement it, maybe there are other ways?

```
import os
import pickle
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'], help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('Bot is ready')
    print('--------------------')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    channel = message.channel
    co = '{0.content}'.format(message).split()
    stock=co[0]
    price=float(co[1])
    print(stock)
    print(price)

    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:86.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0'
    }
    while True:
        async with bot.session.get(
                f'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{stock}?p={stock}.tsrc=fin-srch',
                headers=headers
        ) as r:
            def scrape(html):
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
                content = soup.find('div', {"class": 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}).find('span').text
                return content
            content = await bot.loop.run_in_executor(None, scrape, await r.text())
            con=float(content)
            if price <= con:
                await channel.send("достиг")
                break
        print(f'{stock} {content}')




bot.run(settings['token'])
```

```
stock=co[0]
price=float(co[1])

filename = 'db.json'
myfile = open(filename, mode='w', encoding='Latin-1')

list = []
list.append(stock)
list.append(price)

json.dump(list, myfile)
myfile.close()

myfile = open(filename, mode='r', encoding='Latin-1')
js=json.load(myfile)


for user in js:
    print("Stock: " + str(user['stock']))
    print("prise: " + str(user['price']))
```

Comment: You can simply use json to store data, and update the file whenever the object updates.

Comment: @Ceres yes, but how do I do it?)

Comment: How do I do it is a bit off-topic for this site, I would checkout tutorials like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp), and load the variables at startup and update the file every time i scrap. If you're having troubles implementing that, you could definitely ask another question, but be a bit more precise on what you're asking.

Comment: I write variables in json, but when reading it, an error occurs: string indices must be integers. code: `js = json.load(myfile)`  `for k in js:`  `print(str(k['stock']))`

Comment: How is your json file structured? Looks like it is a list containing string, when it is supposed to be a list containing dictionaries

Comment: look at the code, added it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233363/discussion-between-red-and-ceres).

Answer (score 0):

For the edited question, json simply doesn't work that way. Your variable names aren't stored anywhere, its just the values. If you want key value pairs. You will have to store it as dictionaries. But I don't think you need key value pairs here. So we'll just use a list.

```py
#Assuming you need a list of stocks and their price.

sample_stocks = [('AAPl', 12), ('ANO', 15)] #stocks stored as stock and price
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(sample_stocks, f) # we simply dump the list
    
# Accessing 
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
   stocks = json.load(f)
for item in stockes:
   # sample item is ('AAPl', 12)
    print('stock is', item[0])
    print('price is', item[1])
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend trying out [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb) for that! It has limitations, but it's really easy to get started with compared to SQL-based DBs! You can easily store key-value data in it.